# implement startup class in asp.netcoremvc thermeshb

Tags: asp.net

When like to implement asp.net core start up class to mvc, with entityframework core
we need to implement by this.?
I have implemented by this below code.

1. ====== StartUp.cs file

> 

```
using CoreEntityDBfirstMVCInterface.Interfaces;
using CoreEntityDBfirstMVCInterface.Models;
using CoreEntityDBfirstMVCInterface.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreEntityDBfirstMVCInterface
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        //public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        //{
        //    services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //}

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CompanyDB");
            services.AddDbContextPool<Test2Context>(option =>
            option.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            //services.AddSingleton<IProducts, ProductService>();
            services.AddTransient<IProducts, ProductService>();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Products}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

2. ======== config file (appsettings.json file)

> 

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"CompanyDB": "Server=DESKTOP-N4CKD36\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
    //"CompanyDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
    "CompanyDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

I have implemented by this above code. its works but need below implement as answered by me.

Answer (score 0):

i get answer by myself

> ===>>>> .NET Core

.Net core ma scafold karva ::--
CoreEntityDBfirstMVC
1st in stall entityframework na 3 nugets, design, tools, sqlserver

Khoti below:-
Scaffold-DbContext “Server=DESKTOP-N4CKD36\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True” Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Sacchi below:-
Scaffold-DbContext “Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True” Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Connection strings :--- nicheni 2 mathi koi pan chale (appsettings.json ma) (IMP: DBcontext file ma OnConfiguring() method comment karvi, + default contructor aa file ma comment karvo)

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    //"CompanyDB": "Server=DESKTOP-N4CKD36\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
    //"CompanyDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
    "CompanyDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test2;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
```

Errors:---

1. InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CoreEntityDBfirst.Models.Test2Context' while attempting to activate 'CoreEntityDBfirst.Controllers.ProductsController'.

> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CompanyDB");
>     services.AddDbContextPool<Test2Context>(option =>
>     option.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
>     services.AddControllersWithViews();
> }
> ```

2. InvalidOperationException: The DbContext of type 'Test2Context' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.

solution : Remove the default constructor in the DbContext class, this worked for me

> //public Test2Context()
> //{
> //}

3. page , view ma changes reflect na thay page par to
   Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package to the project
   Add the following in Startup.cs:
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
4. other types of connection strings

> 1]. "AllowedHosts": "*",   "ConnectionStrings": {
> "Default": "Server=server; Database=databasename; User Id=myUserId; password=myUserId@1234;
> Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"   }
>
> 2]. "ConnectionStrings": {
> //"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=School;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
> "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-1234567\SQLEXPRESS;Database=School;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
> }
>
> 3].   
>
> -->
>
> ```
> <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=111.111.1.111\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated
> ```
>
> Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User
> ID=111;Password=11@111;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
> providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
>
> 4].